# Lightning Refresh Console Tab to New Record Type Flexipage

Tags: lightning, record-type, refresh, flexipages, lightning-console

I have a different lightning flexipage intended for different record types. When I click a button on the page it changes the record type (using apex). When I get back from the action I want to refresh the current page so that I can now see the new flexipage.

There are times that this works, but for some reason many times it does not. Is there a reason why at times the refresh doesn't work?

This is a lightning console app.

### What I've Tried

1. `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();`
2. `workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: tabId});`...

   together with...

   `workspaceAPI.openTab({
          recordId: recordId,
           focus: true
       });`
3. `const navEvt = $A.get('e.force:navigateToSObject');
   navEvt.setParams({
       'recordId': recordId,
       'slideDevName': 'related'
   });
   navEvt.fire();`
4. `const navService = component.find('navService');
   const pageReference = {
       type: 'standard__recordPage',
       attributes: {
           recordId: recordId,
           objectApiName: 'Record__c',
           actionName: 'view'
       }
   };
   navService.navigate(pageReference);`

Comment: When the refresh does not work, do you still see the old record type shown in the Record Type field on the page?

Comment: @DavidReed I'm not using the 'Details' tab, so I don't see the Record Type field. I can try to put it back for a moment to see it that's the case.

Comment: @DavidReed I just tried it now and yes I still see the old Record Type in the Record Type field.

Comment: Is there a Visualforce-backed button involved? I'm wondering if it's related to [this known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU).

Comment: @DavidReed It's all in Lightning, no Visualforce. `<lightning:button...`

Comment: @DavidReed Thank you for the known issue link. It states only Visualforce, but I have a feeling it may also be lightning, and the cause of my issue, as this is not the first time I have had refresh issues with lightning.

Comment: Your issue certainly seems to be in the same realm of overzealous client-side caching by the Lightning Experience. I don't know the solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

I do find that one way to force recent Apex updates to be "seen" by the client-side cache is by forcing Lightning Data Service to reload the record. So the same component that is calling the Apex could have an instance of `force:recordData` pointing to that record ID with a FULL layout. It doesn't have to actually use it for anything. Upon return from Apex it can fire the `reloadRecord` method of LDS. I have noticed upon doing this, changed fields will update themselves in the Details panel.

I don't know if this is good enough to also force the change in Flexipage layout. But it's worth a shot. `reloadRecord` takes a callback argument so you can have your console API stuff run after the reload has completed.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this and see if it will work.